# How to achieve carriage return/line break in doctags

Tags: java, javadoc

I want to put this data through the Javadoc:

```
/**
 * 1. line
 * 
 * 2. line
 */
```

How can I make the Javadoc put them on separate lines, like this:
1. line
2. line

Right now, the Javadoc puts them together, like this:
1. line 2. line

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The javadoc comment is basically HTML, so you could use `<br>` to force a line break.